# Cache does not clear in GravityView even after gravityview_use_cache is set to false

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a ranking table using GravityForms that is displayed via GravityView. I have the disabled GravityView cache. But when my cronjob runs, the ranking is not updated. The funny thing is if I add a `?cache` at the end of my URL, the ranking is updated. But, if I immediately access the page with `?cache` after running cronjob, it still shows the old ranking. ONLY after I removed the `?cache` that the ranking is refreshed. It seems very peculiar why this is happening. I even cleared browser cache.

I have the following code in the theme functions.php which disables the cache.

```
add_filter('gravityview_use_cache', '__return_false', 10 ); 
add_filter( 'gravityview_cache_time_entries', 'vr_edit_gv_cache', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'gravityview_cache_time_datatables_output', 'vr_edit_gv_cache', 10, 1 ); 
function vr_edit_gv_cache( $expiration ) {
    $expiration = 1;
    //$expiration = 86400;  // In seconds. 86400 secs is 1 day
    return $expiration;
}
```